# Forgot Player ID for Pokemon.com

Tags: pokemon-tcg-online

I tried to go onto pokemon.com and play the online card game but I forgot my password. I tried to reset it but it wouldn't let me change the password unless I had an ID. I, of course, forgot it. Is there any way I could find it?
(I did fill in the rest of the needed stuff, like my birth date and my username).

Answer (score 0):

Pokemon TCG Online uses your Pokemon Trainer Club account. To recover your username, there's a [*Forgot your username?*](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/forgot-username) link on the [login page](https://sso.pokemon.com/sso/login?locale=en&service=https://www.pokemontcg.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/ptcg-com-caslogin). Simply enter your email to recover your username.